# How to use fixed number of threads to run certain number tasks in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a specific number of threads `THREAD_POOL_SIZE` and a bunch of tasks which can exceed the number of threads. I want to use these `k` threads to run all my tasks. I have these tasks in a `BlockingQueue` and each thread returns a result which should be aggregated later.

Here I wrote a simple program where tasks are numbers from 1 to 100 and I am trying to calculate the sum of all number. Each thread will pick a number from the blocking queue and return it. I am using `Future` to collect my result and sum it later.

The reason for using a BlockingQueue is because I am trying to solve a bigger problem where I can have tasks in a blocking queue and I have certain number of threads to run those tasks.

I would like to know how I can fix the below code to make the `k` threads continue processing entries from the blocking queue?

```
static class Consumer implements Callable<Integer> {
    private BlockingQueue<Integer> sharedQueue;

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Integer> sharedQueue) {
        this.sharedQueue = sharedQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() {
        while(true){
            try {
                return sharedQueue.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 10;
    int BLOCKING_QUEUE_SIZE = 100;
    BlockingQueue<Integer> sharedQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(BLOCKING_QUEUE_SIZE);
    ExecutorService execService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
    List<Future<Integer>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < BLOCKING_QUEUE_SIZE; i++) {
        sharedQueue.add(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_POOL_SIZE; i++) {
        futures.add(execService.submit(new Consumer(sharedQueue)));
    }

    int total = 0;
    for (Future<Integer> future : futures) {
        try {
            total += future.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total count: " + total);
    execService.shutdown();
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add 100 futures to the executor, not 10:

```
for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_POOL_SIZE; i++) {
```

Should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
```

---

It's curious what you think the queue is really adding here. You can massively simplify your code without it.

```
int THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 10;
ExecutorService execService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
List<Future<Integer>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    final int j = i;
    futures.add(execService.submit(() -> j));
}

int total = 0;
for (Future<Integer> future : futures) {
    try {
        total += future.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
System.out.println("Total count: " + total);
execService.shutdown();
```

Comment: Thanks for catching the error. The reason for using a BlockingQueue is because I am trying to solve a bigger problem where I can have tasks in a blocking queue and I have certain number of threads to run those tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Even a glance at your code shows that your code is a way of an overkill. There are java classes that handle this stuff for you. Please look at [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) class and [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class. ExecutorService and its specific implementations provide a managed thread pooling. All you need to do is to invoke method `newFixedThreadPool` of class `Executors` and then submit all your tasks to that pool. You don't need any queue, your tasks will be managed by the thread pool. You can collect your `Futures`and monitor to see when your tasks are finished. It is mor simple then you thought